# Building TensorFlow Lite for Java Desktop without Android

Tags: java, build, bazel, tensorflow-lite

As the title says im attempting to build TensorFlow Lite for Java Desktop without Android. There doesn't seem to be any official guide or build on the Tensorflow Github / Website. Does anyone know of an existing 3rd party maven/gradle link that achieves this, or a concrete way to build Tensorflow for Java desktop without Android.

I've tried the following link but when I preform the steps, I get various Bazel build errors.

https://gist.github.com/JnCrMx/144f3169bde1da6856815b3419122ab0

Comment: You can load the model and run in java as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_java).  And what do you mean by Java desktop. The intent of providing tflite files are for lite devices like Android.  Could you please elaborate your query, if my comment did not help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library for Object Detection in Java. You can have a look if you want: [JavaTF](https://github.com/preafixed/Java-TF)

If you want you can just follow the instructions I provided on the Readme file, and test the functionality. Currently it does not support TFLite, but the saved_model format is quite good too. You can have a look how things are done, I think for a TFLite model it is not much different.

Let me know if it helps :)